# A simple webpage title: simple way to make responsive from horizontal to vertical layout?

Tags: html, css

This website has a hero image with the text "Math Achievement Tutoring." See following code.

The website is responsive in general. As the screen narrows, the title starts to take up two lines, then three. However I don't know how to accomplish the following:

(1) if all title words fit in one line, put them in one line
(2) otherwise put one word per line (use three lines).

I.e. **don't** put "Math Achievement" on one line, and "Tutoring" on the next.

```
<div class="hero"><h1>Math Achievement Tutoring</h1></div>

<style>
   .hero {
      background-image: url("../images/fog.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
   }
</style>
```

This method should work no matter the font or font size used.

Comment: do you have so code someone can start with?

Comment: rather than describing what's happening, providing the code is a much better and efficient way of knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

In your <head> tags, just add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 700) {
     document.location = "Other_page_made_for_little_devices.html";
}
</script>
```

...and create a new page which contains your title in three lines! You can also change the value "700" for something else.

Comment: The point is that I don't know ahead of time where the break width will be, because the font may change. ( #1 the user browser chooses a different font, #2 I swap out fonts during development)

Comment: You just have to add the same script in "Other_page_made_for_little_devices.html", but change "screen.width <= 700" to "screen.width > 700" to reload the first page.

Comment: I mean that I don't know if the number should always be 700.